# Pinging / Validating an IP address

Tags: c++, ping

I currently am working on a .dll file in C++. Basically, for what I am doing if I enter an invalid IP the thing crashes. So how can I validate that an IP is valid?

Is there any way I can ping an IP, and check if there is a response or not without outputting anything to the application?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some code that we can look at? Also, how about a copy of the exact error message you encounter? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you considered fixing your error checking so it doesn't crash? instead of adding another crutch?

Answer (score 0):

First question is really "What is a valid IP address" - one that is technically invalid, such as `345.789.12.18`  - out of range values in the IP address - or one that is outside of your network reach (`10.1.1.1` may not be reachable from where you are, but is technically a valid address if you are on the right network).

My suggestion would really be to fix your crashing application such that it accepts "bad IP" address in some sensible way (invalid IP address gives an error, valid but unreachable gives another error, valid ones that do not "respond" yet another error, valid ones "works").

Yes, you can ping a proposed address - a trivial way would be to `if (system((std::string("ping -c 1 " + ip_address).c_str()) == 0) { ping was ok  }`.

This approach  has several problems. First, the address may well be VALID, but not reachable or some firewalled off for ping, but available for whatever you actually wish to do. Or the opposite, it responds to ping, but not to your requests.

Second, you have TOCTOU (Time of Check to Time Of Use) problems - ping works NOW, but not when you try to use it after checking the ping status, so you still crash.

Yes, writing applications that handle error conditions is often hard. But you should deal with errors, not try to prevent them by checking things that may change later anyway.

Comment: I would still recommend some "sanitizing of an address" rather than feeding it directly to system command as above. Importing it directly into the command line can allow a person to "escape" running the command and do something else.

Comment: Good suggestion. All depends on how much you trust the user and/or where the IP address came from.

Comment: Well, basically I have a plug-in  that checks the status of a SA-MP server. Everything works well with checking if the IP is online / offline as a SA-MP server, but if I enter something such as 127.0. the crash occurs. If you check my last few posts you can find the thread with the code. And this isn't an application run by me, it's an open-source application avaliable to the public, however I do not wish to have this crash for users.

Comment: @user3554138 I checked your activities tab, http://stackoverflow.com/users/3554138/user3554138?tab=activities, and I don't see a question that includes the code. I do agree with Mats about what you mean by a "valid IP address" as there is 1) technically invalid, 2) a valid IP address outside of your current network, 3) a valid IP address in your network that is online, 4) same as number 3 except no system/device responds to that IP address when the ping is done. Are you also using a `try...catch`? If you do use one you should be able to prevent a crash based on the ping. Again,code would help.

Comment: Well what would 127.0, be considered? An invalid format IP?

Comment: @user3554138 That would be invalid IP address for IPv4, whereas an address such as 127.0.0.1 (loopback) or others, such as 192.168.0.1, is a full IPv4 address. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

Comment: To me 127.0 is "too short". But 127.0.0.1 is perfectly valid - it is used as a special loopback address, which is used for example when a network service is being run on the same machine that is using it - e.g. you could configure your SQL service to be located at 127.0.0.1. But the key here is that you need to either make your code more robus so that it recognises bad IP addresses (e.g. ones with less than three dots in them, but that's probably not the ONLY issue that can occur, or ones with non-numeric content)